# jquery.tablesorter.js > sorting mixed-type columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a table that has a column for Days Remaining.  The values in this column are either a number, or 'TBD' (to be determined).  The tablesorter plugin doesn't properly handle the sorting of this mixed-type column.  How could I get this to work properly?

Thanks,
~jk

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own parser

I am not sure this will work, but try searching for tablesorter and addParser and you should be good:

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "SpecialNumber",
  is: function(s) {
   return /^TBD/.test(s);
  },
  format: function(s) {
   return 0;
  },
  type: "numeric"
 });
```